# Migration of Liferay (6.0 to 6.2), missing getEntriesRSS

Tags: liferay

I migrate a project from Liferay 6.0 to 6.2.

Some of my plugins have errors. For example, one of them complains that AssetEntryServiceUtil.getEntriesRSS() is missing.

After a quick search using javadoc ([6.0](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.0/javadocs/index.html?com/liferay/portlet/asset/service/http/AssetEntryServiceHttp.html) and [6.1](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs-all/index.html?com/liferay/portlet/asset/service/AssetEntryServiceUtil.html)) , I realize that the method has been removed in Liferay 6.1.

By the way, I can't find a doc on how to replace this missing method (none of the migration guide proposed by Liferay details that).

My question is simple : how I replace getEntriesRSS in Liferay 6.2 ?
And is there a full migration guide that explains such migration steps ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `getEntriesRSS` was removed from the Asset Entry service in 6.1 so that it can generate the appropriate URL properly. See https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-16993.

As for migration, it appears that you will have to generate your own feed. I would use `RSSAction.java` located at https://github.com/lionah/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portlet/assetpublisher/action/RSSAction.java as a guide.